# Issue running process from a Linux kernel module

Tags: process, kernel-modules

I am attempting to run a process located in `/usr/bin` from a kernel module, and I am doing so using `call_usermodehelper()`. Within my module, I have:

```
int rc;

char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/myProgram", NULL};
char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", NULL};

rc = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);

printk("RC is: %i \n", rc);
```

Sample program of what I have in `/usr/bin`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    char *arg[] = {"firefox", "sample.html", NULL};
    execvp(arg[0], arg);
    return 0;
}
```

After viewing the syslog, I can see that the RC is 0, which indicates that `call_usermodehelper` was a success, but the program never actually ran (it should've opened a Firefox browser). If I traverse to `/usr/bin` and run the process manually, it works fine and does its expected behavior. Not really sure why this is happening and haven't been able to find much online, any ideas?

I found this old post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/call_usermodehelper-problem-849860/ where the user had a similar issue and claimed calls like `printf()` and `system()` don't work, and he fixed it by using `exec()`, which I have been doing originally anyways`(he also used the object file of his program instead, which I tried as well):

```
int rc;

char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/myProgram.o", NULL};
char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", NULL};

rc = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);

printk("RC is: %i \n", rc);
```

**SOLUTION**

After playing with it more and seeing some comments about needed to state environment variables explicitly since we are within the kernel, I changed my kernel module to look similar to this and the browser is now being opened with `call_usermodehelper()`

```
int rc;

static char *envp[] = {
    "SHELL=/bin/bash",
    "HOME=/home/admin",
    "USER=admin",
    "PATH=/home/admin/bin:/home/admin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/admin",
    "DISPLAY=:0",
    "PWD=/home/admin", 
    NULL};

char *argv[] = {"/home/admin/mySample", NULL};

rc = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
printk("RC is: %i \n", rc);
```

Sample program now looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *arg[] = {"firefox", "/home/admin/sample.html", NULL};
    execvp(arg[0], arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need more environment variables to run a graphical program. If you launch a program from within an open graphical session, it's easy to locate the graphical server and everything that is needed, but from the kernel, it's an entirely different problem.

Comment: Can you try again with `DISPLAY=:0` in `envp`?

Comment: Hi, I followed this link for my environment variables, not really sure which more I should be using? All the samples I have come across online follow a similar outline to: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-user-space-apps/

    **static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux", "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };**

Comment: This API is usually used to spawn daemons to perform administrative tasks or "last-chance" programs like core dump generators, so they need less environment.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it with `static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux", "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", "DISPLAY=:0", NULL };` and `char *argv[] = {"/home/admin/myProgram", NULL}; `, again the return code is indicating 0 but no browser is being opened

Comment: @lgeorget Just added some more environment variables and got it to work finally. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice ! Glad to hear that. Please post yourself your answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with it more and seeing some comments about needed to state environment variables explicitly since we are within the kernel, I changed my kernel module to look similar to this and the browser is now being opened with `call_usermodehelper()`

```
int rc;

static char *envp[] = {
    "SHELL=/bin/bash",
    "HOME=/home/admin",
    "USER=admin",
    "PATH=/home/admin/bin:/home/admin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/admin",
    "DISPLAY=:0",
    "PWD=/home/admin", 
    NULL};

char *argv[] = {"/home/admin/mySample", NULL};

rc = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
printk("RC is: %i \n", rc);
```

Sample program now looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *arg[] = {"firefox", "/home/admin/sample.html", NULL};
    execvp(arg[0], arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was dealing with a similar issue, didn't realize that the first value in the `argv` array had to be the path of the program!